# Load gameOver scene when camera collide with a terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here I create an empty for all the terrains tagged Lost

[image]

I want to load the gameOver scene if the player collide with one of these terrains, so I wrote this code, but nothing happens

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class collide : MonoBehaviour
{
    private LevelManager l;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //l = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<LevelManager>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    void OnColliderEnter(Collision c)
    {
        if (c.gameObject.tag == "Lost") {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Lose");
        }

    }

}
```

I'm a beginner at Unity, so please try to explain to me with details.

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you'll specify your problem more accurate. I don'g get it if all of the terrain gameobject's have 'lost' tag, or only Lost gameobject has a 'lost' tag? or does every terrain object has it's own nonstatic rigidbody and any type of collider? there is several possible issues u are encountering and it need to be specified more clear and then I think I can help you

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [OnCollisionEnter()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) instead of `OnColliderEnter()`.

I tend to write to console to isolate one problem at a time.  Maybe verify that you're capturing the collision event first, then worry about the scene change after.

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter(Collider col)
{
    // Apaprently CompareTag is better for performance
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("DeathTerrain"))
    {
        Debug.Log($"This is where you die to {col.gameObject.name}");
    } else
    {
        Debug.Log($"Hit a game object named {col.gameObject.name} that didn't have the tag.");
    }
}
```